# Mysqli select query. Affected_rows doesn't compare words with white spaces

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, whitespace

```
$nick = trim('Your Nightmare');

    $q = connect_db();

    //sprawdzam czy w bazie juz istnieje taki gracz
    $conn = $q->prepare("SELECT name FROM players WHERE name = ?");
    $conn ->bind_param("s", $nick);
    $conn ->execute();
    $conn ->bind_result($db_nick);
    $conn ->store_result();

    if($conn ->affected_rows === 0)
    {
            echo 'inserted~!<br/>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'player already exists!';
    }

    $conn ->free_result();
    $conn ->close();
    $q->close();
```

So if player name is "Your Nightmare" and in database there is player name "Your Nightmare" the code works fine. 
But if player name is "Your space space Nightmare" (notice more spaces(that's why i use trim)) and in database there is "Your Nightmare". 
Looks like affected_rows or num_rows doesn't work for white spaces. Please help! :(
[image]

Comment: `if($conn ->affected_rows === 0)` do you know what that does? It checks if it wasn't so it's not "inserted" yet you're echoing that it is.

Comment: PHP's trim removes white spaces only from from the beginning and end of a string, not from middle. Threfore the "Your space space Nightmare" is not the same as "Your Nightmare".

Comment: if Your Nightmare was not in database then insert it, if it was then player already exists, isnt it? but the white spaces dont work.

Comment: slaakso. you are wrong. it removes spaces from midle, leaving only one space between words

Comment: looks good but have no idea how to use it with prepared staement :( im trying to google it but nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an **equals (=)** operator, that means data must match exactly, the **trim** function only removes spaces from the begining and the end of a string. To remove spaces between words you must use something like **preg_replace** wich allows you to replace a pattern on a string and replace for a new value, in your case you can replace multiple spaces by a single one like this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/i',' ','Your  Nightmare');
```

This will allow you to "normalize" the information received. Read more about *preg_replace* at http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php.

Comment: your code does exactly the same what a function trim does. '_______Your_________Nightmare________' after trim is just 'Your_Nighmare'. but whatever i will try with your code and post the result

Comment: LOL it works, thanks. but have no idea why... cuz trim removed white spaces between words leaving only one space between each word... so its the same. nice job! thank u! :)